# Why is onChanged not called when value changed in LiveData List?

Tags: java, android, android-livedata, mutablelivedata

**Context**

Using `MutableLiveData<List<Integer>>` to hold a values. When the first value (using first value as example for brevity) in the `List` is incremented, `TextView` should update in `onChanged` to display the first value in the `List`.

**Goals**

- Increment first value in a `List`
- Update `TextView` when first item of a `List` changes

**Problem**

1. On `Button` click, the first value in the `List` is incremented but `MutableLiveData.onChanged()` isn't called, why is this?
2. Does `MutableLiveData` only respond to its `setValue` method?
3. Could this be solved via the `List` containing `MutableLiveData` Integers (i.e., `MutableLiveData<List<MutableLiveData<Integer>>`, problematic since requires listeners for each item in the `List`)?
4. Is there a better way to achieve the goals?

**Code**

```
final MutableLiveData<List<Integer>> vals = new MutableLiveData<>();
List<Integer> intVals = new ArrayList<>();
intVals.add(0);
vals.setValue(intVals);

tv.setText("" + vals.getValue().get(0));

vals.observe(this, new Observer<List<Integer>>() {
    @Override
    public void onChanged(@Nullable List<Integer> integers) {
        int firstVal = integers.get(0);
        Log.d(TAG, "onChanged val " + firstVal);
        tv.setText("" + firstVal);
    }
});

btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // first val in List is incremented but onChanged isn't called, why?
        int newVal = vals.getValue().get(0) + 1;
        vals.getValue().set(0, newVal);
        Log.d(TAG, "set val at index 0 to " + newVal);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`LiveData` Observable's `onChanged` method is called only after calling `setValue()` or `postValue().setValue()` should be called only from main thread as `postValue()` should be called from different thread (`onClick` happens on main thread so `setValue()` will do).
Anyway using the code below will get you what you need:

```
btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // first val in List is incremented but onChanged isn't called, why?
    List<Integer> temp = vals.getValue();
    if(temp!=null) // null-safety just in case....
    {
        int newVal = temp.get(0) + 1;
        temp.set(0, newVal);
        vals.setValue(temp);
        Log.d(TAG, "set val at index 0 to " + newVal);
    }
}
});
```

Comment: I was thinking of resetting the `LiveData`'s `List` value but it seemed wasteful but the solution does work (much better than listeners for each item in `List`)

Answer (score -1):

you should call setValue or postValue to update LiveData,otherwise it will not be observed,mostly i;d like you to use postValue cause setValue must be called in main thread